# Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'CustomMarshalers' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.InteropServices'

Tags: c#

```
using System;    
using System.Collections; 
using System.Reflection; 
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers;

namespace mshtml
{
    [DefaultMember("item"), CompilerGenerated, Guid("3050F21F-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B"), TypeIdentifier]
    [ComImport]
    public interface IHTMLElementCollection : IEnumerable
    {
        void _VtblGap1_3();
        [DispId(-4)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(EnumeratorToEnumVariantMarshaler))]
        IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The above code gives me the following error:

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'CustomMarshalers' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.InteropServices' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Pleae advise how to fix? It's a decompiled code, and I am very beginner in C#.

Comment: I just copy paste your code into a new project and is all good. No error. Probably there are some DLL references missing in your project ?

Comment: Not sure exactly, what i am missing

Comment: Only for test, just create a new project and copy paste your code there.

Comment: Yes, you are missing a reference.  Second one in the Add Reference dialog :)  Never decompile mshtml, there is no point to that, you already have the PIA on your machine.  Project > Add Reference > Assemblies > Extensions > select Microsof.mshtml.  And do focus on writing your own code first, you are never going to learn anything useful from trying to hack other people's code.

Answer (score 3):

You have to include CustomMarshalers.dll
Example:
Add the reference using Project -> Add Reference -> Browse -> Go to location **"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\CustomMarshalers\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a"** -> Select **CustomMarshalers.dll**

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for resurrecting an old thread. With Framework 4.72, you can use Project -> Add Reference -> Assemblies -> Check the box next to CustomMarshalers.

Comment: Note that Stack Exchange doesn't really have a "thread necromancy" rule like many forums do.  As long as you can provide a good, unique answer, the age of the question doesn't matter.